# How to load the next page using ajax in a WordPress loop?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to load page2 with AJAX in my dynamic posts loop. I searched for some possible ways and found this guide https://unicorntears.dev/snippets/load-more-posts/ but it didn't come out to be working.

I want to load the next page in the post loop by AJAX, by simply clicking a load more button.

Archive.php I am currently using is

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <main class="main-content">
        <div class="inner">
            <?php if(have_posts()): ?>
            <ul class="product-list">
                <?php while(have_posts()):the_post(); ?>
                <li class="list-product">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="product-thumbnail">
                            <img class="lazyload" data-src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <span class="product-price"><?php if($product->is_type('variable')){echo variable_price_html();}elseif($product->is_type('simple')){echo simple_price_html();} ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Since I am not familiar with JS, I want someone's help. Please someone help me make this happen.

Comment: "but it didn't come out to be working." Exactly what didn't work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: This code should load next page without reloading the page, just a AJAX refresh. but it does not do that. It reloads the page and move to next page which is not at all AJAX.